# Best way to find a folderId

Tags: assets

I'm iterating through a folder using craft.assets, to select the folder I'll use the folderId.

What's the best way to find the folderId of a specific folder?

The only way I've found is to go the the Asset Settings page in the CP and hovering over a folder to see the url in the status bar in my browser.

**Related Problem:**

I created a folder in the CP Fields page (see image) and there seems no way to get this folderId as I cannot get to it in the Asset Settings page. As I only have a small number of folders I was able to figure it but it got me wondering if I was missing the obvious somewhere?

Thanks

John

[image: Folder added in Field page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the id in the database in the `craft_assetfolders` table. Creating a field with *uploads restricted to a single folder* does not create an asset folder. The asset folder only gets created when you actually have an asset in that folder, so before that point there is no `id`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Marion, it does seem there's no simple way within the CP without resorting to querying the db then. Not a problem though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like that

```
// return an associative array with the asset source handle as key
$assetSources = craft()->assetSources->getPublicSources('handle');
$assetSource = $assetSources['yourAssetSrcHandle'];
$assetFolder = craft()->assets->getRootFolderBySourceId($assetSource->id);
$assetFolder->id;
```

I also find weird that there is no direct method to get this from an asset source handle...

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to inspect the sidebar element in the control panel using your browser. The screenshot below shows a *media* folder (id 9) that’s nested under a parent folder (id 1)

[image: screenshot of the CP sidebar’s folder element]

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [blueprint](https://github.com/bjerenec/craftcms-blueprint/) plugin. It doesn't currently do this, but it does similar things.